# How to implement toogle display function in forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am needing to set the "read more" links to toggle the display of the remaining content when clicked.

The script loops through the paragraph elements in the module DIVs. It skips over the first `p` element and hides the remaining `p` elements using the style property. An `a` element is created for each iteration and is appended after the first `p` element. The `a` element when clicked should display hidden `p` elements. How can I rewrite the toggleCopy into the forEach loop function?

```
<div class="module">
  <h2>Sample Heading</h2>
  <p>
  Project summary paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing.
  </p>
  <p>
  Project development changes paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Current for loop with `newLink` functionality added using `addEventListerner`.

```
// Use for loop to select all 'p' elements
function toggleCopy(e) {
  for(let i = 0; i < allParagraphs.length; i++) {
    // Assign each iteration to 'para'
    let para = allParagraphs[i];
    // If the iteration is the first 'p' element, bypass and continue the loop
    if(i === 0) {
      continue;
    }
    // For all remaining 'p' elements, set the 'display' to 'block' if currently set to'none',
    // if 'display' is not set, set it to 'none'
    if(para.style.display === 'none') {
      para.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      para.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  // If the newLink 'a' element has been clicked, remove it from the DOM
  if(this === newLink) {
    this.remove();
  }
  // Check the 'e' event behaviour, and if it is not 'undefined' set 'e.preventDefault' to prevent
  // the default 'href' behaviour
  if(e !== undefined && e.preventDefault !== undefined) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }
}

// Set the event listener on the newLink 'a' element to be 'click', and assign the 'toggleCopy'
// function
newLink.addEventListener('click', toggleCopy);
```

New `forEach` function. Where would the `toggleCopy` function fit in?

```
// Create an anonymous function that executes immediately on load
(function() {
  // Select all of the '.module' divs in the '.modules' parent div    
  let modules = document.querySelectorAll('.module');

  modules.forEach(function (module) {
    let ps = module.querySelectorAll('p');
    let fps = ps[0];

    ps.forEach(function (p, i) {
      // Create 'a' element, and assign to newLink constant
      const newLink = document.createElement('a');

      // Set 'href' and 'class' attributes for the 'a' element
      newLink.setAttribute('href', '#');
      newLink.setAttribute('class', 'read-more');

      // Set the innerHTML text for the 'a' element
      newLink.innerHTML = 'Read more';

      newLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(this === newLink) {
          this.remove();
        }
        if(e !== undefined && e.preventDefault !== undefined) {
          e.preventDefault(); 
        }

        if(p.style.display === 'none') {
          p.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });

      if(i === 0) {
        return;
      }
      p.style.display = 'none';

      fps.appendChild(newLink);
    });
  });
}());
```

Comment: this can be achieved with css, I dont know how but you may google and find a quick solution

Comment: CSS cannot recognize a click event, so this is not a solution.

Comment: there is definetly a solution with css

Comment: Well then please share or stop contributing to this question. Contributors are supposed to help, not be silly and say "Google it". Most of us do that first, then arrive here.

Comment: chill bro, checkout the link
`https://codepen.io/JoshBlackwood/pen/pEwHe`

Comment: @AkhilAravind Thanks for the share, but I noticed that your example uses jQuery with CSS. I am needing to use pure JavaScript as detailed in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185890/discussion-between-akhil-aravind-and-mike-hermary).

Comment: I have updated the forEach code to include my solution for the problem. Comments or suggestions are welcome.